# Retrieving a unique dataset from XML fields in SQL 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I currently have several rows (say around 100 for args sake) in a table, and within that table I have an XML field which contains data as follows (example):

```
<cf1>summer</cf1>
```

.. I might then have another row or rows containing:

```
<cf1>winter</cf1>
```

.. and for completeness, another few rows perhaps containing multiples of:

```
<cf1>spring</cf1>
```

***So my question is:***

How to write a query/proc to return me a unique resultset of all possible  xml nodes in my xml field?

I guess I can return say 100 rows, and then using C# to filter that down.. but I am guessing that with SQL 2008 there are far better ways of doing that!

Comment: Are you looking for unique tags (`<cf1></cf1>`) or unique Inner Text (`summer`,`spring`,`winter`)?

Comment: Sorry, didn't make that clear.. the actual content, so the inner text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that you use XQuery to grab the data in a subquery and just treat it as another row in the table.  Like such:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Season
FROM
  (SELECT CAST(Xml_Field.query('data(/cf1)') AS VARCHAR) AS Season
   FROM My_Xml_Table)
```

This query will return:

```
Season
------
summer
winter
spring
```